# How to use a Dialog throught a app, passing content to it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building my first Vue.js app and I want to open a Dialog ([using Element.io](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US)) components. I want to call a Dialog and pass the content to it.

So my dialog would be "global" and I would pass content to it from different components.

How do I include this dialog? how do I pass arguments to it and so on?

Should I use something like:

```
import Dialog from '../GlobalComponents/Dialog.vue';
Vue.prototype.$dialog = Dialog;
```

or include it in each component, and how would that be?

I have no problem making a event handler for the toggle of the Dialog, just don't know how to call the dialog to open it (or change its `dialogVisible` state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the Dialog as vue component to make it available globally.

```
Vue.component('my-dialog', Dialog);
```

Then in your "main" file / index.html or whatever you use to start your Vue app you define your dialog

```
<my-dialog></my-dialog>
```

If you want it to display errors for example you can use emits and listenters

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue(); // event buts
```

in the created method of your my-dialog

```
created: function() {
    this.$bus.$on('error', function(msg) {
        // access message here
        // make dialog visible
    });
}
```

And wherever an error occurs

```
this.$bus.$emit('error', 'this is my error');
```

If your dialog is more complex you can ofcourse also pass objects instead of strings in the emit

Comment: Nice, very interesting. `+1` So if I add `<my-dialog></my-dialog>` in the outer container of my app I only need to add `<my-dialog></my-dialog>` there right? and then how could I call it from children instances of that outer container/component?

Comment: as said you can setup a global event bus using  Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue(); you can use this bus to emit and listen to events. Every single component you use will be able to call this.$bus.$emit and this.$bus.$on to listen / emit to this global Vue instance.